# Android WebRTC can continue voice call, but can't continue video call

Tags: android, webrtc

I am working on an Android video-audio call application, so far I have made the main functionality, it's working fine no problem I can make: voice call, video call. my problem is that when I press the home button (video gets interrupted for any reason) I can't get it back again, 
the strange thing is that I can do what ever I need with the voice; continue while app is in the background and stop voice, but unfortunately I can't control the video at all. I think that there is a problem in the creation of the video related webRTC stuff so here is the code responsible for that:

```
PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions
            .builder(this)
            .setEnableVideoHwAcceleration(true)
            .createInitializationOptions());


    PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();

    DefaultVideoEncoderFactory defaultVideoEncoderFactory = new DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(),  true,  true);
    DefaultVideoDecoderFactory defaultVideoDecoderFactory = new DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());

    peerConnectionFactory = new PeerConnectionFactory(options, defaultVideoEncoderFactory,defaultVideoDecoderFactory);

    videoCapturerAndroid = createCameraCapturer(new Camera1Enumerator(false));

    audioConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
    videoConstraints = new MediaConstraints();

    //Create a VideoSource instance
    videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(videoCapturerAndroid);
    localVideoTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack("100", videoSource);

    //create an AudioSource instance
    audioSource = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioSource(audioConstraints);
    localAudioTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioTrack("101", audioSource);

    videoCapturerAndroid.startCapture(1024, 720, 30);

    localVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //create a videoRenderer based on SurfaceViewRenderer instance
    localRenderer = new VideoRenderer(localVideoView);

    localVideoTrack.addRenderer(localRenderer);

    gotUserMedia = true;
```

I will be updating the question when needed(i.e. some other code snippet is needed).
Please help, I have been trying to solve this problem for about a week and the only progress I achieved is learning how to control the voice :) Thank u in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spent more time trying to do it, and finally it worked, here is what I did:

I tried to check if the stream is null in the onResume() after I open the app 
again from the sleep (sleep means the home button was clicked) but it wasn't null. after that I decided to see what will happen if I display the stream again in the onResume() (but I needed to check before I display it if it is null cuz it will be null in the first time I open the app). That's all what I had to do to reuse the video stream again, actually that allowed me to flip the camera(front and back) cuz before that I couldn't do that.